# Checking if variable is not empty before WP_query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to test if `$_GET` varriable is not empty before making wp query. I've tried this:

```
($miesto_name != '' ? "array('key' => 'miestas', 'value' => $miesto_name)," : '')
```

In the arrgs:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => 32,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    's' => $_GET['paieska'],
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        ($miesto_name != '' ? "array('key' => 'miestas', 'value' => $miesto_name)," : ''),
        array(
            'key' => 'imones_apskritis',
            'value' => $apskritis_name
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key'       => 'apmoketa'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'city_clause' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'veiklos',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $_GET['veikla'])
    )
);
```

But that didn't worked, is there are any other way to check if value is not empty before doing queries?

I really can't find a way to do this, and i don't want to create separate $args for every condition...

Comment: just out of curiosity, if it evaluates to false, will it insert an placeholder ??

Comment: you should use ```!==``` like ```$miesto_name !== '' ? array('key' => 'miestas', 'value' => $miesto_name), : '';``` posted an answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do

```
$paieska = isset( $_GET['paieska'] ) ? $_GET['paieska'] : 'Value if Get is Empty';
$veikla = isset( $_GET['veikla'] ) ? $_GET['veikla'] : 'Value if Get is Empty';
$custom_array = !empty( $miesto_name ) ? array('key' => 'miestas', 'value' => $miesto_name) : array();
$args=array(
    'post_type' => $type,
    'posts_per_page' => 32,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
    's' => $paieska,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'      => 'AND',
        $custom_array,
        array(
            'key' => 'imones_apskritis',
            'value' => $apskritis_name
        ),
        'city_clause' => array(
            'key'       => 'apmoketa'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => array( 'city_clause' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
        'taxonomy' => 'veiklos',
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'terms' => $veikla
    )
);
```

Comment: Never ever use non sanitized `$_GET` variable values. This is the number one spot used to inject malicious code into a site

Comment: I agree, lets tell OP to sanitized ```$_GET```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make use of the [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function in PHP which will do a few things

- Check if the `$_GET` variable exists
- Return the value if found, otherwise return false
- Sanitize/Validate the value when a filter is set

You should note that you should **NEVER EVER** use non sanitized/non validated data from any `$_GET` variable (*This also goes for any other input into a site like `$_POST` and form fields*). This is favorite spots that hackers use to inject malicious code into a site in order, so if you do not want your site hacked, **ALWAYS ALWAYS SANTIZE/VALIDATE/ESCAPE** any data coming into a site, and never trust anyone, not even yourself

You can simply do something like the following if your `$_GET` value is expected to be a string (*adjust the filter according to data type expected*)

```
$value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'name_of_key', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
var_dump( $value );
```